# DebugDiag dump doesn't include a .NET exception, depending on certain code

Tags: c#, debugging, debugdiag

I'm trying to create a dump using DebugDiag that will contain information for non-handled .NET exceptions.

The creation of the dump file seem to be dependant on the running code, which I don't understand why.

These are the steps I've taken:

1. Prepare a simple console application named `DebugDiagTest` with the following code, which throws an `InvalidOperationException` exception:

   ```
   using System;

   namespace DebugDiagTest
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               if (ShouldAwaitKeyPress(args)) Console.ReadLine();
               Throw();
           }
           static void Throw()
           {
               throw new InvalidOperationException();
           }
           static bool ShouldAwaitKeyPress(string[] args)
           {
               var shouldAwaitKeyPress = false;
               if (args.Length > 0)
               {
                  bool.TryParse(args[0], out shouldAwaitKeyPress);
               }
               return shouldAwaitKeyPress;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Compile and **run with `DebugDiagTest.exe true`**, and DO NOT press any key yet; let it wait for a key press (step 4).
3. Prepare a DebugDiag exception rule (you can follow [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126141827/https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/using-debugdiag-to-capture-memory-dumps-on-first-chance/ba-p/377131)).
4. Go back to the running `DebugDiagTest.exe`, then press some key to make it crash.
5. Go to  `C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\Logs\Crash rule for all instances of DebugDiagTest.exe`, and *you'll see a `.dmp` file*.
6. Now **run with `DebugDiagTest.exe false`**, go again to `C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\Logs\Crash rule for all instances of DebugDiagTest.exe`, and you'll see that *no `.dmp` file was created*.

*You can now re-run `DebugDiagTest.exe true` whatever times you'd like, and see that a dump file is created each time. However, re-running `DebugDiagTest.exe false` never creates a dump file.*

**My question:**
Why running `DebugDiagTest.exe true` creates a dump, while `DebugDiagTest.exe false` doesn't?

Comment: The crash rule only worked once because in step 4 that process terminated. By design.

Comment: @LexLi, that's not true. A dump file is created each time when running `DebugDiagTest.exe true`, while running `DebugDiagTest.exe false`  never creates a dump file.

Comment: DebugDiag needs to attach to your newly started process which takes time. Hence no dump when your process crashes too fast. Why do you not configure WER to create a dump of any process? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps

Comment: @AloisKraus, I just tried out WER and it did work, thanks. In general, I'm not that familiar with dump creation methods, and just went with DebugDiag because it seemed very configurable, allowing to specify specific exceptions.

Comment: The best tool is still procdump which allows you to attach to an existing process or to start your process from procdump or it waits until it attaches to a specific process. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump

Comment: @AloisKraus, great, thanks. Will you post that as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DebugDiag will need to attach to your application. When you crash too fast during startup DebugDiag will not yet have attached to your process and you will not get any dump out of it.

In that case it is easier to set some registry keys of Windows Error Reporting to enable of all or just your exe to take a full dump once your process exits with an unhandled exception.
For more details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
Reg_Expand_SZ DumpFolder e.g. %temp%\WERDumps
DWORD         DumpType   2 is full dump
DWORD         DumpCount  e.g. 10 to keep the last 10 crashed full dumps
```

You can also create a subkey

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\MyApplication.exe
```

to configure dump reporting only for you executable.

If you want to filter dumps based on specific exceptions you can use procdump from SysInternals which allows you to take e.g. a full memory dump on e.g. every InvalidOperationException by

```
procdump -ma -e 1 -f InvalidOperationException myApp.exe
```

Be sure to check out the extended help via

```
procdump -? -e
```

which will give you a overview how powerful that one is.

Comment: Thanks, will reward the bounty once I'm able.